# How to loop through the data from LOOKUP activity in azure data factory

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am reading a specific folder to loop through all the csv files using azure data factory. I have created a pipeline with the following steps

[image]

Copy activity

[image]

My lookup data is as follows I would like to read all the data and process it using a script variable

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "Prop_0": "ABC",
            "Prop_1": "DEF",
            "Prop_2": "XYZ'",
            "Prop_3": "123456789",
            "Prop_4": "10/19/1991",
            "Prop_5": "Male",
            "Prop_6": "Married",
            "Prop_7": "City",
            "Prop_8": "AB",
            "Prop_9": "6226",
            "Prop_10": "",
            "Prop_11": null,
            "Prop_12": "",
            "Prop_13": null,
            "Prop_14": "",
            "Prop_15": "",
            "Prop_16": null,
            "Prop_17": null,
            "Prop_18": null,
            "Prop_19": null,
            "Prop_20": null,
            "Prop_21": null,
            "Prop_22": null,
            "Prop_23": null,
            "Prop_24": null,
            "Prop_25": "11/28/2023 07:43 AM",
            "Prop_26": "11/27/2023 02:20 PM",
            "Prop_27": "12/01/2023 02:37 PM"
        },
        {
            "Prop_0": "PQR",
            "Prop_1": "DEF",
            "Prop_2": "XYZ'",
            "Prop_3": "234567890",
            "Prop_4": "10/19/1991",
            "Prop_5": "Male",
            "Prop_6": "Married",
            "Prop_7": "City",
            "Prop_8": "AB",
            "Prop_9": "6226",
            "Prop_10": "",
            "Prop_11": null,
            "Prop_12": "",
            "Prop_13": null,
            "Prop_14": "",
            "Prop_15": "",
            "Prop_16": null,
            "Prop_17": null,
            "Prop_18": null,
            "Prop_19": null,
            "Prop_20": null,
            "Prop_21": null,
            "Prop_22": null,
            "Prop_23": null,
            "Prop_24": null,
            "Prop_25": "11/28/2023 07:43 AM",
            "Prop_26": "11/27/2023 02:20 PM",
            "Prop_27": "12/01/2023 02:37 PM"
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on the count value I would like to read the the prop values and process, as I am using foreach I can't use it again so can some one help how to read the data and process

Comment: what is your expected output from the above input? And are your files does not have any header?

Comment: I need to read each property and do an insert in to multiple oracle tables

Comment: Why not use a copy activity instead of lookup inside the ForEach to copy each file to oracle table?

Comment: I tried that but seeing like attached

Comment: You mentioned your target is oracle tables. But in your copy activity the target is a File system? the source should be the csv file and sink should be oracle tables in the copy activity. You want to copy all csv files into same oracle or different table in every iteration? if different tables then how the tables names looks like? how you are gonna get the list of those table names?

Comment: My target is from a drive I read all csv files and process to oracle database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256402/discussion-between-rakesh-govindula-and-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, nested For Each loop are not supported in ADF. So, you need to two pipelines as workaround for this. One is a parent pipeline which contains Get meta data activities a loop and lookup to iterate through those files. Second pipeline is a child pipeline which should have a for each activity to loop through the lookup output array.

You need to use a [**Execute pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) activity to call the child pipeline from parent pipeline in each iteration of the loop. Also, you need to pass the lookup output array to the child array as parameter. The child pipeline for each activity will take the array parameter and it will loop through those items.

**This is a sample demo:**

The above pipeline should be your parent pipeline and build your child pipeline like below.

First create an empty array parameter.

[image]

Take a ForEach activity and pass this array parameter to it. If you want the insertion of every row to the table in a sequential manner, check the **Sequential** check box in for each.

[image]

Inside ForEach, take a [**Script activity**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/execute-sql-statements-using-the-new-script-activity-in-azure/ba-p/3239969) to execute your script to insert into the required tables.

Here for sample, I have executed a below script in SQL.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(2048) = N'@{item()}';

select * from openjson(@json);
```

[image]

Here, `item()` means the JSON object in each iteration from the lookup array.

Now, in your parent pipeline, take an Execute pipeline activity after the lookup and pass the lookup output array `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` to the Child pipeline parameter like below.

[image].

Upon Execution of the Parent pipeline, in each iteration, the lookup activity output array of the csv file will be passed to the array parameter of the child pipeline. As we are passing that array parameter to the for loop in the child pipeline, that will iterate through the lookup array.

**My sample output from the child pipeline:**

[image]

**This is my parent pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Parent pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "individual_csv",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "firstRowOnly": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "Child pipeline",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "lookup_arr": {
                                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**My Child pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Child pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.lookup_arr",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Script1",
                            "type": "Script",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "linkedServiceName": {
                                "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
                                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                            },
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "scripts": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Query",
                                        "text": "DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(2048) = N'@{item()}';\n\nselect * from openjson(@json);"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "scriptBlockExecutionTimeout": "02:00:00"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "lookup_arr": {
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** For sample I have used csv files from ADLS GEN2 and SQL instead of oracle. So change the linked service types as per your requirement. Also, cross check the Sequential of both ForEach activities as per your requirement.

Comment: Can I get the oracle script for the same?

Comment: I have added my pipeline Json's which you can use to build your pipeline. You mentioned you have scripts of oracle. Please raise another ask for it so that the community may assist, and I will also try if that's to my knowledge.

Comment: I am able to do as per required thanks for your help