# how to replace single quote in json with a special character in azure data factory

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having the json output as follow from one of the CSV file I had **`"Prop_2":"Horse'"`** I am trying to replace the single quote I tried few things by setting an variable and the expression as follows `replace(@{variables('JsonData')},''', '*')` but couldn't see the output as expected. The data is from the previous question I posted [How to loop through the data from LOOKUP activity in azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77725157/how-to-loop-through-the-data-from-lookup-activity-in-azure-data-factory) so I would like to know how can I format the json as per required.

Comment: what is the value of the `JsonData` variable here? this `"Prop_2":"Horse'"`?

Comment: And Is your replace function is an ADF function or any query function? I see you are using string interpolation of variable inside replace function. Can you provide a picture of your expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below expression to achieve your requirement.

```
@replace(variables('var1'),'''','*')
```

The extra `'` acts as an escape character for `'` in this expression.

[image]

I took the input variable `var1` value as `"Prop_2":"Horse'"`.

**Result:**

[image]

You can see the `'` was replaced with `*` and ignore the `\` because it's an escape character for `"` in the string.

If you want to use the above expression in any query, use the string interpolation expression(`@{}`) in between the query like below.

```
@{replace(variables('<your variable name>'),'''','*')}`
```

Comment: Can I use directly like this? @{replace(activity('FileData').output.value,'''','*')}

Comment: Yes, but replace expects the value to be a string. so if your `activity('FileData').output.value` is an array. convert it to string and use like this `@{replace(string(activity('FileData').output.value),'''','*')}`.

Comment: Check this sample [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572316/18836744) to understand string interpolation with query.